# Sometimes, proxy info is removed from Windows' LAN Settings

Tags: windows, http-proxy

I use Privoxy as a local web proxy.

Sometimes, the proxy infos in Lan Settings are removed, so that I can no longer browse the web until I manually fill in the infos again:

[image]

I ran Comodo Antivirus, but it found nothing.

Has someone experienced this too? Any idea how to catch what application is playing tricks on me?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the proxy you are using? Is it capable of managing it's settings on your machine?

Comment: @Twisty Privoxy. He said in the question ...